# What is the common practice to store users data and analysis it with Spark/hadoop?

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, hadoop, apache-spark

I'm new to spark. I'm used to a Web developer, not familiar to big data.

That's say I have a portal website. user's behavior and action will store in 5 sharded mongoDB clusters.

How to I analyze it with spark ?

Or Spark can get the data from any databases directly (postgres/mongoDB/mysql/....)

Because most website may use Relational DB as back-end database.

#### Should I export whole data in the website's databases into **HBase** ?

- I stored all the users log in postgreSQL, is it practical to export data into HBase or other Spark preffered databases ?
- It seems it will make lots of duplicated data if I copy the data to a new database.

#### Does my big data model need other framework excepts  **Spark** ?

For analyze the data in the website's databases,

I don't see the reasons that I need HDFS, Mesos, ...

[image]

#### How to make Spark workers can access the data in PostgreSQL databases ?

I only know how to read data from text file,

and saw some codes about how to load data from **HDFS://**

But I don't have HDFS system now , should I create one HDFS for my purpose ?

[image]

Comment: these are 3 different questions

Answer (score 3):

Spark is a distributed compute engine; so it expects to have files accessible from all nodes.  Here are some choices you might consider

1. There seems to be Spark - MongoDB connector.  [This post](http://codeforhire.com/2014/02/18/using-spark-with-mongodb/) explains how to get it working
2. Export the data out of MongoDB into Hadoop.  And then use Spark to process the files.  For this , you need to have a Hadoop cluster running
3. If you are on Amazon, you can put the files in S3 store and access from Spark

Comment: As for relational databases: Spark includes [JdbcRDD](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/JdbcRDD.html) which converts result of any sql query into distributed dataset ready for use by workers.